# Recomendation: how to load dynamically a post with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, post, dynamic

I need a recommendation. I want to have a sidebar with all the titles of the posts and by clicking on any of them that this is loaded with its content in the main section of the page. The idea is that when loading the page not all the contents of each post are loaded, but only when clicking. What system can I use if I am using Laravel?

[image]

Comment: please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return your post to the view using your controller:

```php
public function someFunction()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('your-view', compact('posts'));
}
```

Now, within your blade template, use the laravel `@foreach` blade directive to create 
your links to each post:

Wihtin your view, where you want to display the links to the posts in your sidebar:

```php
@foreach($post as $post)
    <a href="{{ route('posts.show', $post->id) }}>
        {{ $post->title }}
    </a>
@endforeach
```

This code will create a link to each of the posts you have.
In order to the `route('posts.show', $post->id)` work, you need to have a resource route for your post controller or define this route:

```php
Route::get('posts/{post}', 'YourPostController@show')->name('posts.show');
```

Then, just write your `show` method withing your post controller:

```php
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    return view('your-view', compact('post');
}
```

Hope it helps.